# Ionic run android - Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs' - windows

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework

When I am trying to run the Ionic app in my real device in windows operating system by using

this cmd:

> > ionic run android

Getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:18:20
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)

Cannot find module 'internal/fs' (CLI v1.7.16)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
OS:
Node Version: v7.7.3
```

Here I am using npm version: 4.4.1

Any quick solution should be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the Android platform when creating the project?

```
ionic platform add android
```

Comment: I have added before I am updating npm. Can I add when after updating it?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda You can do it

Comment: Okay I'll try and let you know

Comment: Same issue no change.. @Nidhin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the commands below to test the app:

1. `ionic serve` (*opens in the browser*)
2. `ionic serve --lab` (*opens in the browser with Android and iOS device*)
3. `Use cordova prepare` `cordova build` and `cordova run` (*opens in your emulator*)

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem with node 7+. I resolved it by switching to 6.9.1 using n(node version manager)

```
>n 6.9.1
> ionic <command>
```